# How to solve the error at right angular bracket in xml

Tags: xml, xml-validation

I am having a xml file. If am validating this file through an xml validator its showing me the error at right angular bracket. For example my xml file is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<scenario>
....
</scenario>
```

error is at `<scenario">"`.. Can anybody knows how to solve this error?

Comment: For example my xml file is like

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<scenario>

Comment: error is at <scenario">"--- right angular bracket

Comment: Is that all what the validator says? "Error"?

Comment: yes ... error at right angular bracket

Comment: May I suggest a better validator? Even if you drag your file into a regular web browser (Firefox, IE...) you'll possibly get a better error message. If that's not an option, you should post an actual file that fails so we can test it ourselves.

Comment: There are several possible causes; the likeliest is probably that the schema specifies required attributes for the `scenario` element.  Since you don't provide or point to the schema or DTD, it's impossible to know for sure.  Álvaro G. Vicario is right to suggest getting a validator with better diagnostics.

Comment: thank u C.M Sperberg-McQueen and Alvaro G. Vicario.. i am posting my actual file.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<scenario>
<init>
  <send channel="trans-ip-v5">
    <command name="CER">
      <avp name="Origin-Host" value="pruthvi.localhost.com"> </avp>
      <avp name="Origin-Realm" value="pruthvi.com"> </avp>
   <avp name="Auth-Application-Id" value="4"> </avp>
     </command>

  </send>
    <receive channel="trans-ip-v5">
    <command name="CEA">
    </command>
  </receive>
</init>

<!-- Traffic -->
<traffic>
<send channel="trans-ip-v5">


<command name="AAAR">
</command>

Comment: Sorry...this is not letting me to add the whole file

Comment: Alvaro G. Vicario -- give me that validator.